Regex pattern to find all matches in string with conditions
I am currently stuck with a regex problem.
I have a string:
Take dog, dog, dog, cat, dog;
Dont dog, dog, cat, dog;

How would I match all of the "dog" and skip "cat" with pcre2 regex engine.
The output I want is:
dog, dog, dog, dog;

This would be taken from the first line, because it starts with "Take" which is static. I cannot use any \s* in backtracking, because this doesnt support infinate backtracking.
The regex will be used in another tool, so only pure regex is allowed (no scripting).

What operating system including the release? What are the exact conditions? Is the output only supposed to be take if the line begins with Take? Should it still match for lines beginning with Taken or Take_Over? Does case matter? It it just the first line or some or all of the other lines?

Here is a way to go using PCRE2:
(?:^Take|\G(?!^)).*?\Kdog

Demo & explanation
